# Directed graph of bank balances and transactions, how to process transactions?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, directed-graphs

I'm working on a game where there are several different entities represented by nodes. Each node has a starting balance, and directed edges show where money is owed from one account to another.

One problem I'm trying to figure out is which order to process transactions in, take this example below:

[image: Initial balances and amounts owed]

If you start by processing node 'B', because there is no balance, the \$30 is not transferred to node C. Node A only receives \$20 instead of \$50, bringing the balance to \$50. 'A' can't afford to pay both D and B, so depending on which is paid first the result is different. If D is paid first the balance goes up to \$80. The remaining \$20 goes to B. Then B also receives \$80. The final graph is:

[image: One possible final result]

Is there an algorithm for solving situations like this? Is this related to network flow graphs or is that something different? I'm trying to figure out what problem class this is.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  Is your question whether or not it is possible to pay all the debt?  What happens when A owes 20 to B but only has 10?  Does B receive 10, with A still owing 10?

Comment: Let $v_A$ be the money A has, let $L^-_A$ be all incoming links to $A$ and $L^+_A$ be all outgoing links from A.  Then if you for each person X let $t_X = v_X + \sum L^-_X - \sum L^+_X$, then you have the surplus/deficit for each player.  If all values are non-negative, then it is possible to pay off all debts.

Comment: What happens if you have a cycle $A {{1}\over{\rightarrow}} B {{1}\over{\rightarrow}} C {{1}\over{\rightarrow}} A$ and everyone's balance is 0?

Comment: If you find a cycle with _bottleneck value_ $b$ (i.e. the smallest value of the cycle), can we then deduct $b$ from all edges of that cycle, or do you demand that each player actually pays that money?

Comment: The above question also stands wrt transitivity, if $A {1 \over \rightarrow} B {1 \over \rightarrow} C$, can we shortcut it to $A {1 \over \rightarrow} C$ instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your rules, here's a greedy algorithm:

Maintain a priority queue of all nodes where the value in the queue is *how many debts they are able to pay down*.  Let the debt for each player be sorted by value.

Pop off a player $X$.  If $X$ can pay, pop off the first debt.  Then update the recipient's balance, and the number of debts they can pay off (binary search), and update the PQ.  Then you push $X$ back onto the PQ with its updated count.

All in all, this should take $O(m \log m)$ time where $m$ is the number of debts.